# Azure Functions missing assembly reference in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I'm trying to understand why vs-code is giving me this error

> The type 'Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.
> You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
> [AzureFunctions]csharp(CS0012) class
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.FunctionNameAttribute (+ 1 overload)

on the following code.
The error above comes from the **[FunctionName("UploadGhost")]** line below

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
    
namespace My.Functions
{
    public static class UploadGhost
    {
        [FunctionName("UploadGhost")]
        [StorageAccount("AzureWebJobsStorage")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            //[Blob("ghostsdev/{name}", FileAccess.Write)] out string ghostfile,
            ILogger log,
            IBinder binder)
        {
            ...
```

I can "Go to definition" on **FunctionName**, and the function works when I deploy it, but for some reason VS Code still complains about it and the whole .cs script file is full of red underlines.

Answer (score 1):

fixed it by settings "Omnisharp: Use Global Mono" to "never" as was suggested here: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/3290